# How do I separate an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ok, so I have an array:

```
numbers = ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

and I need to split the array into two arrays with a conditional

```
numbers.reject!{|x| x > 4 }
```

and what i need is one array `numbers` to contain `numbers = ["5"]` and another array with the rejects `rejects = ["2", "3", "4"]`

How do I do this? ...It seems so easy with a loop but is there a way to do this in a one liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

```
arr = ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
numbers, rejects = arr.partition{ |x| x.to_i > 4 }
 # numbers = ["5"]
 # rejects = ["2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: Nice one-liner.  I'm going to submit a more verbose one.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5]

n_gt_four = numbers.select{|n| n > 4}
n_all_else = numbers - n_gt_four

puts "Original array: " + numbers.join(", ")
puts "Numbers > 4: " + n_gt_four.join(", ")
puts "All else: " + n_all_else.join(", ")
```

Outputs:

```
   Original array: 2, 3, 4, 5
   Numbers > 4: 5
   All else: 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Just because I'm in a silly mood: `n_gt_four = numbers.select(&4.method(:<))`. ;-)